# How to add searchable items to logback, similar to traceId in slueth

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a springboot application which is using sleuth. Which creates logging you can search on.
So the following logging code

```
log.info("Request from client "+clientId);
```

will return

```
@timestamp:Dec 30, 2021 @ 16:52:22.855, message: Request from client client111, traceId: 111 spanId: 111
```

But as well as having timeStamp, message, traceId and spanId, I also want to add clientId. so that I can have

```
@timestamp:Dec 30, 2021 @ 16:52:22.855, message: Request from client client111, clientId: client111, traceId: 111 spanId: 111
```

Now I know I add clientId to logback.
But how do I code it in the jave code to pick up the clientId.

Log.info writes to the message only, is there a way I can also get it to write clientId to clentId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Mapped Diagnostic Context MDC

so in my code I have

```
MDC.put("clientId",clientId);
logger.info("received from client"+clientId);
```

in my logback.xml

```
 %X{clientId} - %msg%n"
```

Comment: please add to your answer a proper example of your `logback.xml` with the proper pattern so is useful for others who could have the same issue

Comment: Actually I used it again, and you dont need to add to logback.xml. The key is using MDC